# How to ensure server security when mod_rewrite is enabled

Tags: .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite, joomla2.5

I am being informed by the team that manages the servers that enabling mod_rewrite will excessively compromise the server security.

Are they correct?

What can be done to make sure sever security is minimally compromised if at all after enabling the mod_rewrite.

I am not able to clean up joomla urls without mod_rewrite enabled.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

They're not correct as the issue depends exactly how "mod_rewrite" is tuned.
You can:
Enable "mod_rewrite" for your specific site/virtualhost and not other sites by using directives such as [RewriteEngine On] and then tune the rewrite code to handle what to do should someone ask for inappropriate url etc.
Remember the server itself is tuned by using other directives and the code within "mod_rewrite" block needs to handle itself as a block.

Here is docs and examples of "mod_rewrite" blocks
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite together with poorly crafted rewrite rules can potentially weaken your security but as with any server software, the key to keeping your server secure is to configure the software properly and keep it up to date.

mod_rewrite is widely used in conjunction with WordPress, Joomla and Drupal and it seems unlikely that this would be the case if it "excessively compromises" security.

*Not* using mod_rewrite could be a security issue too as the native Joomla URLs are visible and this gives hackers information about the extensions you have installed on your website.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5009900/1983389

Comment: Thanks Neil for the reply